# Powershell convert tabbed text file content to well formatted HTML Table

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I want to process a text file to well formatted HTML table in powershell, below is the file content -

```
Machine ID  Proc Name   Proc Inst  Status         Comment             
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1           BG          1          RUNNING        BG process started  
1           BG          2          RUNNING        BG process started  
1           BG          3          RUNNING        BG process started  
1           BGPREDICT   1          RUNNING        BG process started  
1           DLMGR       1          RUNNING        DLMGR process started
1           IAPJMS      1          NOT RUNNING                        
1           RPCBG       1          RUNNING        RPCBG process started
1           RPC_TCP_LI  1          RUNNING        RPC listener process started
1           RPC_UDP_LI  1          RUNNING        RPC listener process started
1           SPO         1          RUNNING        SPO Server process started
1           SPO         2          RUNNING        SPO Server process started
1           WIS         1          RUNNING        WIS process started 
1           WIS         2          RUNNING        WIS process started 
1           WIS         3          RUNNING        WIS process started 
1           WIS         4          RUNNING        WIS process started 
1           WIS         5          RUNNING        WIS process started 
1           WIS         6          RUNNING        WIS process started 
1           WISMBD      1          RUNNING        WISMBD process started
1           WISMBD      2          RUNNING        WISMBD process started
1           WQS         1          RUNNING        WQS process started 


Timed out waiting for system status response.
```

I am not able to convert as they appears same to HTML Table form, but getting everything in single cell in each row  by using below snippet-

```
Get-Content $env:TEMP\stat.txt|ConvertTo-HTML -Property
   @{Label='Text';Expression={$_}}
```

Header from text file should be same in HTML Table under  rest all shoul dbe treated as  with each cell respectively to

Please help me to achieve this.

Comment: You will first have to split your text file in proper columns and the only common point I see is to split at more than one space and even this is difficult with empty trailing columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This script does the parsing into an object using several RegEx replaces to form a csv and then using the `ConvertFrom-Csv` cmdlet:

```
$table= (gc .\sample.txt -raw ) -replace "-{10,100}`r?`n" -replace "`r?`n *`r?`n"
$table -split "`r?`n" | %{
    If ($_ -notmatch 'Timed out'){
        "`"{0}`"" -f ($_ -replace " {2,15}",'","')
    }
}|ConvertFrom-Csv | ConvertTo-html | Set-Content .\Sample.html -Encoding UTF8
```

Sample `ConvertFrom-Csv`output

```
Machine ID Proc Name  Proc Inst Status      Comment
---------- ---------  --------- ------      -------
1          BG         1         RUNNING     BG process started
1          BG         2         RUNNING     BG process started
...snip..
```

Is piped to `ConvertTo-html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>HTML TABLE</title>
</head><body>
<table>
<colgroup><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/></colgroup>
<tr><th>Machine ID</th><th>Proc Name</th><th>Proc Inst</th><th>Status</th><th>Comment</th></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>BG</td><td>1</td><td>RUNNING</td><td>BG process started</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>BG</td><td>2</td><td>RUNNING</td><td>BG process started</td></tr>
...snip...
```

And saved to a file you can view in your browser:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your code, but I am using PS 2.0 where -raw, replace with GC are not working -PSVersion  2.0, any alternate way if you could give?

Comment: Why didn't you use the `powershell-v2.0` tag first place? Going to sleep now, evtl I'll take a look tomorrow.

Comment: can you please help me to have alternate logic please?

Comment: Sorry, but no. Never had deeper experience with v2 restrictions and there should always be a recent Pc with Windows10 in reach. May be you better delete this question and ask again with mentioning PSv2 and posting the csv as text rather than an image.

Comment: Upgraded PS and woks perfectly.

Comment: This little snippet helped me so much with an unrelated, albeit similar, task. I cannot thank you enough! @LotPings